# Migrations Error in Django: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I know this has been asked before. But, I tried the available solutions. Those don't seem to work in my case unless I missed something unintentionally.

I dropped all the tables/relations from the connected database and deleted all the previous migration files except the **init**.py. And then ran the makemigrations command which worked fine. But got this error after running migrate.

Here is the error:

```
Applying book.0001_initial... OK
Applying reader.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/brainiac77/github/bookworms_backend/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/brainiac77/github/bookworms_backend/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 93, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
File "/home/brainiac77/Installations/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 440, in create_model
    if field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

reader.0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.6 on 2022-08-01 07:57

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('book', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Reader',
            fields=[
                ('rid', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('photo_url', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('bio', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('read_books', models.ManyToManyField(through='reads.Reads', to='book.book')),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
        options={
            'db_table': 'reader',
        },
    ),
]
```

Reader model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Reader(models.Model):
    rid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    read_books = models.ManyToManyField('book.Book', through='reads.Reads');

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'reader'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return {
            'username': self.user.username,
            'first_name': self.user.first_name,
            'last_name': self.user.last_name,
            'email': self.user.email,
            'photo_url': self.photo_url,
            'bio': self.bio,
        }
```

Book Model

```
from django.db import models

from genre.models import Genre
from reader.models import Reader

class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13,primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    page_count = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Reader, related_name='authored_books')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return {
            'isbn': self.isbn,
            'title': self.title,
            'description': self.description,
            'photo_url': self.photo_url,
            'page_count': self.page_count,
            'created_at': self.created_at,
            'updated_at': self.updated_at,
            'genres': self.genres.all(),
            'authors': self.authors.all(),
        }
```

Reads Model:

```
from django.db import models

from reader.models import Reader
from book.models import Book

class Reads(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        ('w', 'Want to Read'),
        ('r', 'Reading'),
        ('c', 'Completed'),
    )
    rsid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    reader = models.ForeignKey(Reader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_choices)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'reads'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return {
            'reader': self.reader.user.username,
            'book': self.book.title,
            'created_at': self.created_at,
            'updated_at': self.updated_at,
            'status': self.status,
        }
```

INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # local apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'reader',
    'book',
    'genre',
    'reads',
    'bookreview',
    'library',
    'librarystock',
    'bookborrow',
    'friend',
]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the migration file (reader.0001_initial.py) is wrong. There the foreign key table is `book.book`, which should be `book.Book`.

So I think you need to clear all the migration files and rerun the `makemigrations` command.

You can remake the migration file for the `reader` app using the following command.

```
python manage.py reset_migrations reader
```

Comment: Thanx for your response. I did that to avoid circular import as the Book model is also importing Reader model. And according to [this link](https://www.alpharithms.com/django-circular-imports-153910/), using this string based specification is a workaround.

Comment: I changed my answer. You don't need  to set `ManyToMany` field in both models.
So just remove and set the `related_name` attribute instead in the `Reader` model.

Comment: Actually there are two different m2m relations between Book and Reader. One is the author from the Book model and another was the Books the reader is currently reading (basically reading list).

Comment: Ah... I understand. Then can you show me the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py` file here?

Comment: Sure, I have added in the main question.

Comment: I changed my answer. You need to rerun the `makemigrations` command.

Comment: This is what I did. cleared all the migration files, dropped all the database tables, run makemigrations, edited book.book to book.Book in reader.0001_initial.py manually, run the migrate command, got the same error. Did you mean something else?